# How to modify Start method variables in the Update method : Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm just having a little trouble figuring out how to modify a set variable in the Start method within the Update method. Example:

```cs
 void Start()
    {
        // We know what min and max are, so we will set their value instead of updating later on (when something happens, etc.)
        int max = 1000, min = 1;
        int guess = (min + max) / 2;

        Debug.Log("Welcome to Number Wizard");
        Debug.Log("Pick a number...");
        Debug.Log("The highest number you can pick is: " + max);
        Debug.Log("The lowest number you can pick is: " + min);
        Debug.Log("Tell me if your number is higher or lower than my guess: " + guess);
        Debug.Log("Push up = Higher, Push low = Lower, Push Enter = Correct!");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        foreach (KeyCode single_key in control_keys)
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(single_key))
            {
                /*Debug.Log(single_key + " key pressed!");*/
                if (single_key == KeyCode.UpArrow)
                {                              
                    Debug.Log("It's higher? Okay, I'll guess higher.");
                }

                else if (single_key == KeyCode.DownArrow)
                {

                    Debug.Log("It's lower? Okay, I'll guess lower.");
                }

                else if (single_key == KeyCode.Return)
                {
                    Debug.Log("I got it !");
                }
            }
    }
```

I want to update the guess within the Update loop method, but if I try to do something like this when the guess is too low:

```cs
min = guess + 1;
```

I get this error:

```cs
The name 'min' does not exist in the current context.
```

If anybody has experience in Unity and could help me out that would be much appreciated.
Note: I know I could create a global variable (like my control_keys array), but I thought there must be a way to not just assign a bunch of global variables

Comment: If you declare variables in Start, then they are local to Start. Once Start ends, they are gone and released to the garbage collector. You cannot reference them elsewhere because they no longer exist. It is quite right when it says `min does not exist in the current context`. In fact, by that time it exists in no context whatsoever. Once variables go out of scope they are gone. At least in interpreted languages..

Comment: @DetectivePikachu C# is a compiled language, but that statement remains true (though local variables and probative types are more likely to exist on the stack and not need to be GC'd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you declare inside of a method 
- or to be exact in general a code block - is a "local variable" and only exists within this method's (code block's) scope.

(See e.g. [c# variable scopes](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx) for more information.)

---

Just make them class fields by declaring them outside of `Start`

```
// You also can directly define fields with a default value.
int max = 1000;
int min = 1;

int guess;

private void Start ()
{
    guess = (min + max) / 2;
}
```